# Why does my tile palette not arrange nicely?

Tags: unity, tilemap, hexagonal-grid

I made my own Hex Point Top Tile sprite sheet, ensuring it's pixel perfect and align well. Slicing in Sprite Editor has no problem too. However, when I drag the sprite sheet to a new Palette in the Tile Palette panel, the tiles show up with random spaces. See screenshot below:
[image]

What did I miss?

The sprite sheet is here, 30 x 30px offset, 24 x 24px padding, 66 x 66px tile size:

[image]

I'm using Unity 2019.3.10f1.

Comment: I'd suspect this is just due to rounding. The automated layout tries to place the tiles in a similar position to where they were in the original sprite sheet, and that doesn't align exactly to the tile palette grid. So some tiles get nudged a little to fit into the nearest cell, leading to a repeating pattern of gaps. Can you simply move the tiles to have the packing you want?

Answer (score 1):

Your tiles don't fit the background grid. For your tall tiles, the bottom sprite boundary aligns with the low edge, but the top sprite boundary aligns with the high edge. On the right, I've marked the tile size you provided in blue, and the actual tile size in red.

[image]

Additionally, the hexagons on the bottom have a different shape than the hexagons on the top: on the left, I marked the bottom hexagon outline in blue and overlaid the top outline in red. They'll never fit together properly.

If you want to create proper hex grids, you'll need a fixed template shape that serves as the *base* of your hexagonal prisms, not the entire outline. You can make the actual tiles as tall as you want, as long as the base is always in the same shape and at the same position. Of course the bottom slope needs to be the same as the top slope too.

If you want your hexagons to be regular hexagons, then the vertical ratios of the template need to be 1:2:1 as depicted here:

[image]

The ratio of height to width is left up to you, it will correspond to a different apparent view angle.